# Круг и кружка — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология

Считаются ли слова *круг и кружка* однокоренными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагается, но сомнения остаются. Есть варианты.

[КРУГ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3)

> Происходит от праслав. *krǭgъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   ст.-слав. крѫгъ (др.-греч. κύκλος), русск., укр., белор. круг, болг.
>   кръг(ъ́т), сербохорв. кру̑г (род. п. кру̑га), словенск. krȏg, чешск.,
>   словацк. kruh, польск. krąg (род. п. kręgu). Восходит к праиндоевр.
>   *krengh-. Ср.: др.-исл. hringr, др.-в.-нем., англос. hring «кольцо», умбр. cringatro, krenkatrum «cinctum, повязка на плече как знак
>   отличия».

[КРУЖКА](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> Происходит от неустановленной формы. По одной версии, из др.-русск.
>   крѹжькъ (ср.: русск. кружок), связано с круг; по другой — из польск.
>   kruż «кувшин», связанного с ср.-в.-нем. krûse и далее — с греч.
>   κρωσσός «кувшин».

Это Фасмер рассуждал. А Крылов его слегка подправляет:

[**Кру́жка.** Видимо, образовано как уменьшительное от заимствованного из немецкого Krug — «кружка, кувшин».](https://krylov.lexicography.online/%D0%BA/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

"Кружка" произошло от слова "круг", соответственно, эти два слова являются однокоренными

Answer (score 2):

1) Слово ***круг***  в др.-рус. языке известно с XI века: кругъ, кружьный, а с XIII века — круглъ, круглый. Прилагательное ***круговой*** в словарях с 1771 года. О.-с. основа krogъ, и.-е. корень ger с неясным колебанием gr/kr.

2) Слово **кружка** — более позднее (XV-XVI век, причем исключительно в новг. и псков. говорах): ***кружка и крушка.*** Хотя происхождение слова  неясное, скорее всего, не славянское. Вероятное **заимствование из германских  языков,** где обозначало не только кружку, но и просто кувшин для питья. С другой стороны, на формирование этого слова в русском языке слова ***круг, кружок*** могли оказать влияние.

3) Поэтому более вероятно то, что слова ***круг и кружка***  формально не являются однокоренными (изначально кружка — это не обязательно круглый сосуд, а словообразование "круг — круглый" в историческом плане не просматривается очевидно).

4) В современном языке кружка обычно действительно круглая, но словообразование *круг — кружка* или *круглый — кружка* **не соответствуют существующим схемам.**

5) О прилагательном **круговой**:

У Пушкина ковши круговые, кубок круговой — то, что пускалось по кругу. **КРУГОВО́Й** (толковый словарь Ушакова) прил. к круг; движущийся по кругу. Круговое движение. Круговая чаша (чаша вина, из которой все пьют по очереди, вкруговую).